# Why do F# functions evaluate before they are called?

Tags: module, f#, functional-programming, evaluation

If I define a module as such:

```
module Module1
open System

let foo =
    Console.WriteLine("bar")
```

Then, in interactive do

```
#load "Library1.fs" //where the module is defined
open Module1
```

I see a

> [Loading c:\users\jj\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Library1\Library1\Library1.fs]
>   bar

Indicating that the foo function ran without me even calling it!

How/why does this happen?  Is there any way to prevent it?

I'm aware that the return value of foo is whatever (Console.Writeline("bar")) evaluates to, and that there isn't any reason that can't be evaluated "immediately?" (when the module is loaded I guess?) - but is there a way to prevent it from happening?  If my module functions alter the state of some other stuff, can I ensure that they do not evaluate until called?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Function bodies are evaluated when the function is called, just as you want. Your problem is that `foo` is not a function, it's a variable.

To make `foo` a function, you need to give it parameters. Since there are no meaningful parameters to give it, the unit value (`()`) would be the conventional parameter:

```
let foo () =
    Console.WriteLine("bar")
```

Accordingly a call of this function would look like `foo ()`.

Comment: *value* seems to be a better term than *variable*.

Comment: @bytebuster The way I see it, `()` is a value. `foo` is a variable that's bound to that value. Look at it this way: Values are what expressions evaluate to. An expression can evaluate to, say, `()`, `1` or `"Hello"`. It can't evaluate to `foo`, that's not yet the end result of the evaluation.

Comment: @sepp2k I'm not sure it makes sense to say that `foo` is a variable. In the original question, I would consider `foo` to have the value `()`, it just happens that printing to the console is a side effect of producing that `()`. I also think that saying a partially evaluated function is not a value may be misleading, since I think one of the core concepts is that functions *are* values too. I think the term variable should be reserved for things that can be rebound to a different value (vary), which `foo` cannot in these cases.

Comment: @ryachza A partially evaluated function is a value, right. That's not what I was trying to say. I was referring to the foo of `let foo = ...` and trying to distinguish between the variable (or "placeholder" if you want) and its value (`()`). Anyway I strongly disagree that the term "variable" implies mutability. The concept of mutability never existed in maths where the term "variable" comes from, so I don't see why it should be part of its definition.

Comment: @sepp2k a late reply: variables in math are names for changing things though: in `f(x) = x^2` `f` is not a variable and in general agreement `pi := 3.141...` `pi` is a constant. Now `x` *is* a variable but called *parameter* or *argument*, in the context of one evaluation of the function, it is constant though. Constants are values in F#, as are [let bound names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/functions/let-bindings), a name bound to a value. Usually there's no need to differentiate between values and their names, so we call the name value.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `let foo = x` is essentially a static value that gets evaluated immediately, once. If you want a parameterless function, you would need `let foo () = Console.WriteLine("bar")`, using it as `foo ()`.

If you don't want to have to use the parentheses when calling, something like `type Test () = static member foo with get () = System.Console.WriteLine("bar")`, using it as `Test.foo` should work.