# F# main vs main() syntax

Tags: syntax, f#

I am just trying to learn some F# by going through the Wikibook: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/

Consider the following example from:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Mutable_Data

```
open System

let withSideEffects x =
    x := "assigned from withSideEffects function"

let refTest() =
    let msg = ref "hello"
    printfn "%s" !msg

    let setMsg() =
        msg := "world"

    setMsg()
    printfn "%s" !msg

    withSideEffects msg
    printfn "%s" !msg

let main() =
    refTest()
    Console.ReadKey(true) |> ignore

main()
```

I realized that they put () after every function which has side effects. Removing the braces compiles equaly well and changes the type from unit -> unit to unit.

**Questions:**

1. Is this some kind of silent aggrement between F# programmers?
2. Are there any benefits for one of the 2 syntaxes?

Comment: Also [Why do F# functions evaluate before they are called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855383/why-do-f-functions-evaluate-before-they-are-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `()` to a binding changes it from an immediately executing block, where the return value is bound to the identifier (`unit` in this case), to a function that accepts `unit` and returns `unit` (written as `unit -> unit`).

The advantages of this is that the execution is deferred and can be executed multiple times. This might be a useful way to abstract away side effects, but it's just a simple property of the language you can use in your day to day toolkit. You might be overthinking it.

Comment: Ah :) So if i would have  a function getJSON = .. it would get executed immediatly and therefore my program would wait for a small time before executing main() ?

Comment: Without () it wouldn't be a function taking a ``unit`` and returning something, it would be a value which was assigned by evaluating the block. So yes, there would be a delay before main was executed.